# Select data with a join from 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I just started learning SQL now and trying to figure out this scenario:

We have 3 tables:

```
Clients (ClientID, Name, Surname, Age)
Products (ProductID, Name,    Price)
Purchases (PurchaseID, Date, ClientID, ProductID)
```

What would be the best SQL query that will show the amount of purchases (total amount per client) made by clients?

It must only show the clients who made more than 1 purchase.

The result should contain the following fields: Full name, Quantity of purchases, Total amount.

I've got this query but it only joins two tables. How do I join the third table (Products.Price) as well and calculate the total amount per client?

```
SELECT  CONCAT(IFNULL(Name,''),' ', IFNULL(Surname,'')) as FullName,
        COUNT(purchaseId) as "Quantity of purchases"
FROM Purchases as P
INNER JOIN Clients as C 
on P.ClientID = C.ClientID
GROUP BY C.ClientID,Name, Surname
HAVING COUNT(PurchaseId) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you use `CONCAT_WS()` to combine the first name.  This handles `NULL` values more elegantly than your solution.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(c.Name, c.Surname) as FullName,
       COUNT(*) as num_purchases,
       SUM(pr.price) as total_price
FROM Clients c INNER JOIN
     Purchases p 
     ON P.ClientID = C.ClientID INNER JOIN
     Products pr
     ON pr.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY CONCAT_WS(c.Name, c.Surname)
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.PurchaseId) > 1;
```

Note the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` in the `HAVING` clause.  This ensures that the clients have at least two *purchases*.  If you only want clients with at least two products or purchases, then you can use `COUNT(*)` -- but your question is about purchases.

Comment: Thanks! I did intend to find the amount of purchases and not products.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below -

```
SELECT  CONCAT(IFNULL(Name,''),' ', IFNULL(Surname,'')) as FullName,
        COUNT(purchaseId) as "Quantity of purchases",sum(price) as totalamount
FROM Purchases as P
INNER JOIN Clients as C 
on P.ClientID = C.ClientID
inner join Products p1 on p.productid=p1.productid
GROUP BY C.ClientID,Name, Surname
HAVING COUNT(PurchaseId) > 1
```

Comment: @ShmenuShmenulu . .  . I am surprised that you accepted this answer.  It returns clients who have purchased more than 1 *product*, not with more than 1 *purchase*.  Your question is clearly about purchases and not products.